# After remove row from table with invalid value next row has incorrect 'invalid' css

Tags: c#, blazor-server-side, blazor-validation

NET Core 3.1 etc, Blazor Server

I have a table with few rows. I can add and remove rows by adding to list or removing items from list on server side.
My input field has simple validation using DataAnnotations [Required]

Example. 2 rows. When delete first one with input field "invalid" because it is empty, the second row move up to the first row place. And input field with filled data is like invalid, because has red border, but not have error message.
For the input field I use Blazor InputText.

[image]

Can somebody help me to resolve this issue?

With best wishes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add an @key on row. Easy to resolve.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#use-key-to-control-the-preservation-of-elements-and-components